# Media Queries: Screen > 1024

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to apply media queries in a site but my knownledge is not deep in this topic, so basically I want to apply a specific style to a tag when the detected screen is greater than 1024*768.

I did this

```
@media screen and ( device-width: 1024px ) {

}
```

but the I've to identify when the resolution is greater than 1024

Comment: Is the height relevant? You have the answer right in your tags pretty much, did you try a "CSS media query"?

Answer (score 48):

Try this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1025px) {
    .classname {
        /* styles here */
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) {
    .classname {
        /* other styles here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Use a standard media screen query.  The query will trigger the style changes once the width is 1024px or greater.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    /* Styles go here */
    #layout {
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
  #css {
    foo : bar;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1920px) {
```

html { background: red; }
}

Comment: Could you add some explanation what your code does and how it's different from other answers