# Responsive Design - Image Sizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a site that uses Bootstrap. I'm working to make this site work on both desktop and mobile browsers. Everything's working except for my banner image size.

I have an image that is 640x480. I have an image defined like this:

```
<img alt="My Picture" src="/wwwroot/img/banner.jpg" style="height: auto; max-height:320px; max-width: 100%;" />
```

On mobile pages, the image looks just like I want. However, on the desktop, the image is only 320px wide. However, on the desktop, I want the image to go as wide as it can go. Basically, I want to crop the right portion.

Is there a way to do this with CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Stick your CSS in a class.
- If using HTML5 remove the superfluous `/`
- Change your max- to min- regards height.
- Change your standard width: to auto, changing you

CSS:

```
.imageFun {
    height: auto; 
    min-height:320px; 
    width:100%;
    /* this is actually no longer needed but kept for posterity */
    max-width: 100%;     
}
```

HTML:

```
<img alt="My Picture" src="/wwwroot/img/banner.jpg" class="imageFun">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query to target the img in css file:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
    img {
       width:100%!important;

    }
}
```

That should work changing the `min-width` to your desktop size.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975758/media-queries-screen-1024)

Answer (score 0):

on twitter-bootstrap you can use div with class responsive width :

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img alt="My Picture" 
          src="/wwwroot/img/banner.jpg" 
          style="height: auto; width: 100%;" 
    /> 
</div>
```

Where value 12 is width scala on grid bootstap. Please look at : https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

i hope it what U want

Answer (score 0):

You are using Booststrap, so remove the inline styling and add
 `class="img-responsive col-xs-12`

That will fix it.